# UISearchDisplayController click-through bug on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

We use the standard UISearchDisplayController in a project built on iOS 6.1 SDK. There appears to be a bug when running the application on an iOS7 device - The controller lying underneath the modal controller gets the user interaction instead of the UISearchDisplayController.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on the search bar to give the UISearchDisplayController focus (modal view is shown on top of the viewcontroller lying underneath and the search bar is moved to the top of the window)
2. Write something in the search field to get the table view with results to show up
3. Click on the clear search field icon (X) or backspace the text in the search field
4. Now the modal view is shown instead of the table view
5. At this point if the user clicks on the modal view, the click is caught by the viewcontroller lying underneath the modal view causing faulty behaviour. This problem still remains even if the table view is shown again after the user has done another search.

Has someone else noticed this bug, and has anyone a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sounds like an Apple bug. Please open a new radar for this issue. I can however say that this does not happen when compiling against the SDK7, so it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Time to upgrade, yes. But that means a lot of new coding as well - This is at the moment one of few known bugs in our application, which is why we just want the quick fix. ;)